# Fields missing in result set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

After executing this procedure, in my result set, I got only 2 fields, I could not trace out the bug. I got only Sl No and TypeofDocument in my resultset

My code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('PrGetDetails') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE PrGetDetails
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE PrGetDetails
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    DECLARE @ReportDetails TABLE(
        SlNo INT,
        TypeOfDocument NVARCHAR(150),
        Supplier NVARCHAR(150),
        CodeNo NVARCHAR(150),
        ReceivedDate Date,
        ST_C DECIMAL(20,2),
        ST_D DECIMAL(20,2),
        EC_C DECIMAL(20,2),
        EC_D DECIMAL(20,2),
        HC_C DECIMAL(20,2),
        HC_D DECIMAL(20,2)
    );

    INSERT INTO @ReportDetails (SlNo,
    TypeOfDocument,
    Supplier,
    CodeNo,
    ReceivedDate,
    ST_C,
    ST_D,
    EC_C,
    EC_D,
    HC_C,
    HC_D)
    values 
    (1,'A','S1','AAJF7LSD01','2014/04/04',4362.00,0.00,87.00,0.00,44.00,0.00),
    (2,'B','S2','AAJFV87LSD1','2014/04/04',2520.00,0.00,50.00,0.00,25.00,0.00),
    (3,'C','S3','AK6009T001','2014/04/08',10498.00,0.00,210.00,0.00,105.00,0.00),
    (4,'D','S3','AJ6009LST1','2014/04/16',45723.00,0.00,914.00,0.00,457.00,0.00),
    (5,'E','S4','AAKPK8983001','2014/04/16',171.00,0.00,3.00,0.00,2.00,0.00),
    (6,'F','S5','AKIPM8938P001','2014/04/16',14952.00,0.00,299.00,0.00,149.00,0.00),
    (7,'G','S6','AKIPM8938P001','2014/04/16',28849.00,0.00,577.00,0.00,288.00,0.00),
    (8,'','S7','AABCA7375CST042','2014/04/23',60000.00,0.00,1200.00,0.00,600.00,0.00),
    (9,'','S8','AABCA7375CST042','2014/04/23',1482.00,0.00,30.00,0.00,15.00,0.00),
    (10,'','S8','AABCA7375CST042','2014/04/29',250800.00,0.00,5016.00,0.00,2508.00,0.00)

    SELECT * FROM @ReportDetails
END
GO
```

Comment: which 2 fields? why are columns in the insert not the same name as when you declare it?

Comment: After fixing the error mentioned by @user3468982, This returns all the columns. you may be getting cached results in your SSRS.

Comment: i refreshed local cache but could not get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to your project folder, delete the xxxx.rdl.data file. Then retrieve the data again. As I tested with your procedure, it can return all fields and records properly.

[image]